# how can I install one newer symfony package with flex

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-flex

I want to have an app in symfony 3.4, but to have symfony/dotenv in v4. The [dotenv package in version 4.4.8](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/dotenv#v4.4.8) supports symfony/process 3.4.

But when I run `composer update`, it fails and only lists 3.4.* as candidate versions. This is probably restricted by `extra.symfony.require`: 3.4.* in `composer.json`.

I know it works at least in some cases. I have a project in symfony 3.4 which uses `symfony/http-client 4.3`. Does this only work because there is no older version?

Where can I find more information about dependency restricting by `symfony/flex`?

Here are some sources I know:

1. https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony5-upgrade/version-constraints#symfony-flex-symfony-extra-require-is-a-soft-requirement
2. https://github.com/symfony/flex/blob/master/README.md
3. https://flex.symfony.com/

And here the clearest one:

4. [How composer `extra.symfony.require` restriction is enforced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59166939/how-composer-extra-symfony-require-restriction-is-enforced)

When `extra.symfony.require` is a soft requirement (text from 1.), what does this mean? Does this match to 4.?

---

example of `composer.json` which fails to run `composer require symfony/dotenv:^4.0` (created with `symfony new --version=3.4`):

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.0.8",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/console": "3.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "3.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "3.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "3.4.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "3.4.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to install `symfony/dotenv`  in v4, you should require it. Running `composer update`  won't do that

Comment: I edited composer.json by hand. So `composer update` would update (if it could). When I run `composer require symfony/dotenv:^4.0` instead, it fails as well. The error message says `Could not find package symfony/dotenv in a version matching ^4.0`.

Comment: Please share more details, for example the current state of your `composer.json`. As you can see on https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/dotenv, there are package versions matching `^4.0`, so I think the problem lies in any other part

Comment: composer.json is in question now. I still think that this is restricted by `extra.symfony.require`. When I delete this, then it works. But then I get a mixture of symfony component versions.

Comment: Well, yeah, obviously. That line tells you that Symfony packages should match `3.4.*` - have you tried installing `symfony/dotenv:^3.4`?

Comment: Of course the matching version of symfony/dotenv works. My question still is: Why does it work with `symfony/http-client:^4.3` but not with `symfony/dotenv:^4.0`. And already in the original question I suppose *Does this only work because there is no older version?*.

Comment: according to https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony5-upgrade/version-constraints#comment-4914776956 (comment to my question in 1.), it is a soft requirement for upgrades, but NOT for installations.   --   I am almost sure that `symfony/http-client:^4.3 ` worked because there is no older version.